# How to Upload the File using Selenium to Div tag. Which tag is not having input as type

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to upload file to the div tag.  Its not having type as file input. So please people suggesting sendkey with file path please check my full question.

I have tag like this.

[Screenshot of the tag](http://prntscr.com/ns2dol)

I have tried sendkeys with finding element and upload file from local in that. which did not work out for me.

here what I have tried.

```
GlobalVariables.chromeDriver_Main.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"card-uploader\"]"))
                    .sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Dhaval Bhimajiyani\\Documents\\Lightshot\\Screenshot_207.png");
```

Which is giving me error like this.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

I need to get idea about how i can upload file to this div tag. Which is not having input type as file.

Thank you for your response in advance.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: If you can provide [mcve] maybe we can help. But as your question stands, it's a guessing game.

Comment: You need to provide your markup, or a link to the site in question in order to gain help.  Selenium upload functionality only works with an `<input type="file">`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
# get the button element
ele = driver.find_element_by_id("card-uploader")
# add a hidden file input ( might have to change the onchange event based on the events associated to the button in above line as you don't have a form)
driver.execute_script("var x=  document.createElement('INPUT');x.setAttribute('type', 'file'); x.setAttribute('onchange','this.form.submit()');x.setAttribute('hidden', 'true'); arguments[0].appendChild(x);",ele)
# send the file path here ( this should upload the file)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("C:\\Users\\Dhaval Bhimajiyani\\Documents\\Lightshot\\Screenshot_207.png")
```

Comment: I am not having input as file. Please that into the consideration

Comment: The above code will add an input field (hidden) in line 4 and complete the uploading in line 6.

Comment: Btw I could test this code as I don't find a sample screen.

Comment: Trying to get this work. I will give you sample screen soon if that does not workout. Thanks.

Comment: Cool! Is it possible to share the sample screen, so that I can test it from my end and make any necessary changes/ improvements.

Comment: This is the biggest nastiest hack I've ever seen in my life and is unlikely to work on most well written sites, if it does work you have a potentially massive security hole because you cold upload all sorts of files to the remote server...

Comment: @Ardesco Thanks for your comment. We are trying this approach if this will resolve the current OP issue. If yes, then Krishna can consider reaching out to security team as you mentioned it's `potentially massive security hole` (I am sure that there will be a server side validation, checking what type of file is coming as part of upload)...